# Transmission Parameters for a 2nd order butterworth bandpass filter

Tags: circuit-analysis, inductor, transfer-function, passive-networks, parameters

[image]

I am trying to find the transmission parameters (ABCD parameters) for the above circuit.

$$a_{11}= \frac{V_1}{V_2} |I_2=0$$
$$a_{12}= -\frac{V_1}{I_2} |V_2=0$$
$$a_{21}= \frac{I_1}{V_2} |I_2=0$$
$$a_{22}= -\frac{I_1}{I_2} |V_2=0$$

I have performed an analysis for when $$V_2 = 0$$ and concluded that $$V_1 = (sL_1 + \frac{1}{sC_1})I_1$$ $$I_1 = -I_2$$ so therefore $$a_{12} = sL_1 + \frac{1}{sC_1}$$  $$a_{22} = 1$$

However, these results seem incorrect, so how should I find the transmission parameters for a circuit like this? Especially for the section with $$I_2 = 0$$ which seems much more complex.

Comment: The answers will be involved and might need a page or two of scrawl to fully derive. Were you expecting a picnic by a river LOL.

Comment: I know the second section is likely a pain to derive, I didn't expect someone to work that fully out or anything, but I wanted help on the first section. It didn't seem to take too long on paper, at least by the method that I was doing, or could I have made a wrong assumption in my analysis?

Comment: Why don't you use ABCD for each individual component and do matrix multiplication to solve the full circuit?

Comment: Is that possible? How would you find the ABCD for a lone inductor or capacitor?

Comment: Aha I thought you might be trying to run before you could walk. Yes, it's the basic you should have learnt before jumping in at the deeper end: https://electronics106.jimdo.com/app/download/7409260654/11+Lecture.pdf?t=1510654592 - look towards the end.